# Redirect to App Store from iOS Application when name contains spaces?

Tags: ios, app-store

I am having problems redireting from my iOS app to the App Store. I am using the URL:

```
itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/app_name
```

but with no success. My app name has spaces in which cannot be used in the above example. Is there a way around this. Is it not possible to use the bundle identifier to redirect to the app store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a link like that:

http://www.itunes.com/app/AppName

- Upper-/lowercase doesn't matter
- Remove any spaces and punctuation

Example:

`Doodle Jump - BE WARNED: Insanely Addictive!`

will be:

http://www.itunes.com/app/DoodleJumpBEWARNEDInsanelyAddictive

Comment: Jip! Thanks. Good thing I can read German, but you should probably translate to English for other people. - nvm, thanks!

Comment: Would still be interesting to know, any way of using the bundle identifier?